# How to send an IP packet in vxworks?

Tags: ip, vxworks

I am developing a packet filter in vxworks platform.For that, I need to send an individual IP
packet. Can anyone say which is the simplest way for doing it? Can I use RAW socket in vxworks
as like linux?

Thanks & regards,
Likhin

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use RAW sockets. Take a look at [sockLib](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/sockLib.html)